# Trying to use aggregations in java using the ElasticsearchRepository to fetch aggregated data from Elasticsearch. But my aggs are always null

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, resthighlevelclient

Java = 8
ElasticSearchServer = 7.16.3

My code never returns the value for aggregations , I tried most of the combinations. Below is the code , please see if you can help here

```
@Repository
public interface ScPayHkIndexRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ScPayHkIndex, String> {
   Stream<ScPayHkIndex> findByStatusNotAndExceptionTypeAndTimestampBetween(String status, String exceptionType, long from, long to);
   Stream<ScPayHkIndex> findByPaymentTypeAndTimestampBetween(String paymentType, long from, long to);
   
   @Query(("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match\": {\"status\": \"Completed\"}}]}},\"aggs\": {\"percentAggs\": {\"percentile_ranks\": {\"field\": \"Total_Time\"}}}"))
   SearchHits<ScPayHkIndex> getPercentileRank();

   
   default double getMyPercentileValue() {
       SearchHits<ScPayHkIndex> response = getPercentileRank();
       Aggregations aggregation = response.getAggregations();
       
       PercentileRanks percentileRanks = aggregation.get("percentAggs");

       // Get the desired percentile value using the percentile() method of the Percentiles object
       double myPercentileValue = percentileRanks.percent(5000);

       return myPercentileValue;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get aggregations with repository queries in Spring Data Elasticsearch. You will need to create a `NativeQuery` with the required aggregations and need to use the `ElasticsearchOperations` to process that query.

You do not specify what verison of Spring Data Elasticsearch you use, but looking at the tag `resthighlevelclient` and the Elasticsearch version you seem to be using an old version which is deprecated now.

Comment: Adding rest high level client versions

rest client version = <elasticsearch>7.9.3</elasticsearch>